# Drop rows in a dataframe based on the data type of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

We have a dataset called df and we have a column in it called 'team_id' in the dataframe. And the df[team_id].dtype is object.

And you can see from the attached image that most of the data in the team_id column is a string except there are two 58 which are integer. And what I want is to drop all the rows related to 58, that is to say how could I delete all the rows in a dataframe that its team_id data type is not string(is 58). Thanks!

My idea is like:

```
df_clear = df.drop(df[df['team_id'].dtype != object].index)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `str.isnumeric()` method:

```
df_clear=df[~df['team_id'].str.isnumeric()]
```

**OR**

other way is to use `str.isalpha()` method:

```
df_clear=df[df['team_id'].str.isalpha()]
```

**OR**

another way is to use `pd.to_numeric()` and `notna()` method:

```
df_clear=df[~pd.to_numeric(df['team_id'],errors='coerce').notna()]
```

**Note:** only `to_numeric()` method can handle `NaN's` so If `NaN's` exists in column **'team_id'** then you have to use `dropna()` method for using `str.isnumeric()` and `.str.isalpha()`

Comment: Thx, it said I need some reputations to upvote. And what about float, like there are both 58 and 5.8 in the column team_id.

Comment: that is also a numeric so don't worry whether it is float or int untill it is `NaN` as `str.isnumeric()` and `.str.isalpha()` can't handle `NaN's`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for missing values if no numeric, so then filter in [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df_clear = df[pd.to_numeric(df['team_id'], errors='coerce').isna()]
```